# How to programatically hide/remove categories in charts?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a stacked column graph and i want to hide/show some of the categories on certain conditions. All solutions, i've found, work for series, but in need for categories.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recorded a macro while I filtered my chart to hide category 2, and here's what the recorder gave me:

```
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(2).IsFiltered = True
```

Comment: I tried to record a macro too. But for me it didn't recorded that process of hiding the data. I tried your line an it works. Gonna rewrite my sub. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. However, maybe somebody has a more elegant solution, it would be much appreciated.

1st i swap series and categories.

```
chartSheet.ChartObjects("chart").Chart.PlotBy = xlColumns
```

2nd then i check which column is hidden and save an index for `FullSeriesCollection`. With a little convoluted way to get the sheet name and column address, where the data is located.

```
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    Dim tmp() As Variant
    Dim sh As String, col As String
    For i = 1 To Sheet2.ChartObjects("tst").Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
        If Worksheets(Split(Split(Sheet2.ChartObjects("tst").Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Formula, ",")(2), "!")(0)) _
        .Range(Split(Split(Sheet2.ChartObjects("tst").Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Formula, ",")(2), ":")(1)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To k)
            tmp(k) = i
        End If
    Next i
```

3rd after that i run through all the hidden columns and hide the corresponding data. I couldn't combine 2nd and 3rd, because if any other column, then the last one, is hidden, vba gives an error. Since it tries to access `SeriesCollection`, which does not exits anymore.

```
For i = 1 To UBound(tmp)
        chartSheet.ChartObjects("chart").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(tmp(i)).IsFiltered = True
Next i
```

4th and lastly i flip series and categories back around.

```
chartSheet.ChartObjects("chart").Chart.PlotBy = xlRows
```